# Disallow robots on woocommerce .txt not working on Bing/Google/Yahoo

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, robots.txt, yoast

I am having trouble stopping Google/Bing and Yahoo from crawling specific products on my Woocommerce store. 
The urls I want to exclude from search results are 
https://www.url.com/product/mm6040my/
https://www.url.com/product/mm6041my/
etc

So I am adding this lines to the robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /product/mm6040my/
Disallow: /product/mm6041my/
```

but it's not working.

On another note, I selected the option "Allow search engines to show this Category in search results?" to NO on the Woocommerce category settings (this is with Yoast plugin). But it's not working either.

Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong?
I appreciate it

Regards

Comment: Is there an X-Robots-Tag header being set?

Comment: @user2182349 I am not sure how to set up X-Robots-Tag in this case, could you please help me to understand?

Comment: Yoast has good resources for this - https://yoast.com/?s=X-robots-tag